# Cant use custom view from inside the framework

Tags: swift

I have created a custom textview which uses a custom font. This works smoothly as a separate project.

I have made a framework with the same class. Now when I try to use the custom textview from the framework inside another project, the font is changed. I think it should be because I load the font in the custom textview as UIFont(named:"") and this is somehow not accessible when inside a framework. But I am not sure about it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your "custom" textview should be a sub-class of your frameworks textview

or you simply forgot to import it in your view controller

Comment: I am directly creating the CustomTextView object defined in the framework.. and yes its imported

Comment: But I dont want that.. I need to directly use the same in my IB and use it as a reference

Comment: well swift doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: who was talking about multiple inheritance? Sorry but I think that you misunderstood my question